# xlwings for Excel for Mac 2016

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I am using mac OS X Sierra with Mac for Ecel 2016 and python 3.6. I am trying to launch a python script from excel because:

- I already have an excel with a lot of functionalities and I would like to add some features to this product using Python.
- The users of my product won't be comfortable launching python scripts from a python console, so I'd like to have some kind of excel user interface.

I am providing this background because I am open to suggestions on how to do differently. From my researches so far, it seems that this can be done using the xlwings library. I have tried using it following the instructions on:

http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html#vba

I am somehow stuck at this stage:

*Open the VBA editor with Alt-F11
Then go to File > Import File... and import the xlwings.bas file. It can be found in the directory of your xlwings installation.*

As alt + F11 doesn't open the macro editor, I have understood the instructions as follows:

- click on the 'macros' button in the 'developper' tab of excel
- create a new macro / edit an existing one
- go to 'add references' on the bottom left corner
- open the file mentioned

The issue is that I can't open the xlwings.bas file ; I can only open some of the files. I managed to open a file called xlwings.xlsm ; that creates a new tab called 'xlwings' on Excel, in which there is one button: 'import Python UDFs'. When I press this button it throws the error :

*Run-time error '53':
File not found: xlwings64.dll*

In one of my previous attempts using xlwings, I had a different error at this stage. I cant remember it, but from my researches the solution implied doing something on the trust center of excel 2016 which I couldn't do with Excel for Mac 2016.

Alternatively, when I try to run a macro using RunPython, it throws the following error :

*Compile error:
Sub or Function not defined*

Pointing at RunPython...

If someone knows what I did wrong and/or how I can manage to use xlwings, that would be great.

Thank you for the help,

Comment: Have you tried before to download and run one of the examples here: https://www.xlwings.org/examples ? The excel files in these examples should already include all the requisite VBA code. It won't directly solve your problem, but it might give some useful clues.

Comment: Thanks for the help ; not all functionalities are working (in fact it's not possible to use RunFrozenPython which is not supported by Mac), but at least some are... I guess that the brutal approach is then for me to take that already set up excel and change it for the purposes of my project...

Comment: From what you're describing I don't think you were in the right screen for loading the 'xlwings.bas' file. Try looking for a button in the Developer tab labeled 'Visual Basic', this should open the correct screen (namely the VBA Editor screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your information, the best solution that I found (thanks to Xukrao) was to download an example from [xlwingsexamples](https://www.xlwings.org/examples), go to the macro editor, copy the "xlwings" module that is in the example worksheet and paste it in the macros of my worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to create a new project according to https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/command_line.html is to use the CLI

```
xlwings quickstart myproject
```

This will create an .xslm and a .py file.