# Python Xlwings Not Running

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Trying to launch a simple python hello world script that populates a cell in an Excel sheet using XLwings.

Was hoping to accomplish this simple task before using this approach to run something more elaborate. Unfortunately even this simple tasks seems to not be working. When I run the script off of a button push in Excel, the Excel file just says 'Running...' and nothing happens.

This also happens if I download and attempt to run the [test files from XLwings](https://www.xlwings.org/examples).

I've looked at multiple posts here including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116012/xlwings-for-excel-for-mac-2016), as well as the docs and Youtube to attempt this.

Here's the python script:

```
import xlwings as xw

def SayHello():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wb.sheets['test'].range("A1").value = "Hello World"
```

And here's the Excel VBA code:

```
Sub Call_Python_Function()
RunPython ("import hello; hello.SayHello()")
End Sub
```

I've added the XLwings.xlam file to the working directory, also enabled macros and the developer tab, ensured that XLwings was included in Excel Add-Ins, and enabled the xlwings.conf tab following the instructions on that sheet... and still nothing happens.

I'm a complete Excel n00b. Is there maybe something I missed in the set up for Excel? Have literally never run a macro before so wondering if there is something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the xlwings (xlwings.xlam) add-in to Excel with the shell command `xlwings addin install` (see: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html#add-in )
2. Run `xlwings quickstart myproject` or `xlwings quickstart myproject --standalone` to create your workbook (https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html?highlight=standalone). Consider using a fully qualified path for myproject.
3. Confirm the add-in is installed as a reference in Excel (unless you use the xlwings quickstart --standalone command).  To do this, open Excel's VBA Editor (Alt+F11) > Tools > Refernce... > [Browse...].
4. You will find a working hello world procedure in Module1 within your new workbook.  Make sure this works before trying your own code.

If these steps do not address your concern. Respond with how you are kicking off the procedure and the exact error you receive.  Also, don't be afraid to run it using the Excel debugger (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel_macros/excel_macros_debugging_code.htm).

Comment: thanks. i followed the steps, created a project called 'test' then created a button in the new spreadsheet to run the function. got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'main'

Comment: The error is from Python passed to Excel.  Xlwings found the test.py file, but test.py does not contain a "main" function.  Open the xlwings addin code: xlwings addin > Utils module > ShowError() function (password = "xlwings").  ShowError() calls ReadFile().  Add breakpoint to last line of ReadFile.  You can now see the logfile name and file content, which will give you the full python error stack.  The python traceback will help you identify the exact line of Python code raising this error.  Use this over and over again for all kinds of Python errors passed back to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. For me it was the version of `xlwings` installed in `conda` environment. The force upgrade was done with `conda install -c conda-forge xlwings`. After that I reinstalled the excel addin with `xlwings addin install` command. Python code runs as intended thereafter.